# Restoring a git repository

Tags: git

We had an issue (our hosting account was hacked) over the weekend that resulted in us having to download a backup of our repository, roll our server back to an update from the 6th of dec and then re upload and extract the folder containing the repository.

Now that the most up to date files are in place, what should I do to ensure that git is using these files.

I tried doing a `git add .` and it just seems to hang, as well as attempting `git status`

Comment: well, that's strange. I would suggest to copy the files and the backed up .git/ folder to another filesystem and re-try. What does `git log` say?

Comment: the git logs reflect the commits through the 23rd which is accurate. nothing has been commited since then

Comment: When you say "the repository" what do you mean? Did you upload a copy of the files in your code base? Did you upload the `.git/` directory from a server backup, which was a copy of the master/shared git repository on the server? This reads as vague to me, I'm not sure what it was you did to perform the restore.

Comment: we uploaded the .git/ and the code base

Comment: I would play with the data on a local workstation to be able to control what's going on. Also I would start from a given `.git/` and _empty_ working dir and issue `git status` there. If it passes Ok, then add a single file and repeat the course. It's hard to say what is your problem, because it seems that theoretically you did everything right. If you repeatedly get hangups then it's time to inspect the problem slowly step by step

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are asking. How can u be sure that git use the files? the files are in your folder